# TeamCity - How can I make a parameter for the build to not run one of the steps?

Tags: teamcity

I would like to make it so that a person can kick off a build but choose not to run the unit tests step of the build. My idea is the user would modify one of the configuration parameters when they click the little "..." button next to the "Run" button. It would be cool if they could pick the "True" or "False" from a drop down menu for the parameter. Not sure how to put a condition on the build step executing though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally execute a TeamCity build step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530688/conditionally-execute-a-teamcity-build-step)

Answer (score 5):

It's not built into Teamcity, yet. There's an [open job](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17939) for it, but no indication of ETA.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two different configurations, one that runs all and one that skips the unittests passing the config parameter.  Not exactly what you asked but at least your users can pick which flavor they want to run.