# How to prevent TeamCity XML report processing from failing build

Tags: build, teamcity, mstest, trx

I've got some build content that may or may not generate TRX reports, depending on the configuration; this build content is running on TeamCity.  I also have an XML report processing build feature enabled so the test results can be reported if they are generated.  This build feature seems to be failing the build if no TRX files are found.  Is there any way to get parse TRX results if they exist but avoid failing the build otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, not yet.

There is currently an issue raised with JetBrains to add this functionality https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17939 - you can go there and vote for it to make it a higher priority.

This question is also similar to:

- [How to run a build step conditionally in TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158624/how-to-run-a-build-step-conditionally-in-teamcity?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Conditionally execute a TeamCity build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530688/conditionally-execute-a-teamcity-build-step)

Comment: Alright, good to know.  I wonder if it might be possible to put an empty/dummy TRX in the search directory in an effort to fool the build feature.  I'll have to try to figure out what the minimum requirements are for TRX content, and whether those will pollute the actual test results summary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to keep the XML/TRX report processor from erroring out: copy a dummy TRX file into a directory searched by the processor.  I took a TRX file generated from a successful test run, stripped out some content and replaced various attributes with placeholder values, and marked the `UnitTestResult` outcome as `"NotExecuted"`.  TC will display the test results like this:

[image]

This is the content of the dummy TRX file that I used.  It's a bit of a hack, but at least it keeps the build from failing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestRun id="0240f32b-a8c9-4ad5-ae23-c7b64fe32cd2" name="TrxPlaceholder" runUser="User_Placeholder" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
    <Times creation="2018-04-06T14:10:21.7011071-07:00" queuing="2018-04-06T14:10:21.7011176-07:00" start="2018-04-06T14:10:20.5775149-07:00" finish="2018-04-06T14:10:21.7220949-07:00" />
    <TestSettings name="default" id="40f31577-b2c8-4f67-845f-58155fce4a2b">
      <Deployment runDeploymentRoot="Placeholder" />
    </TestSettings>
    <Results>
      <UnitTestResult executionId="9658777a-f6f7-40cb-a331-95cfec3d7b91" testId="7a75abda-f387-442f-bcb3-fca6aa0ce577" testName="TrxPlaceholder" computerName="Placeholder" duration="00:00:00.0073781" startTime="2018-04-06T14:10:21.3332054-07:00" endTime="2018-04-06T14:10:21.5447253-07:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="NotExecuted" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="9658777a-f6f7-40cb-a331-95cfec3d7b91" />
    </Results>
    <TestDefinitions>
      <UnitTest name="TrxPlaceholder" storage="c:\temp\TrxPlaceholder.dll" id="7a75abda-f387-442f-bcb3-fca6aa0ce577">
        <Execution id="9658777a-f6f7-40cb-a331-95cfec3d7b91" />
        <TestMethod codeBase="c:\temp\TrxPlaceholder.dll" executorUriOfAdapter="executor://mstestadapter/v2" className="TrxPlaceholder" name="TrxPlaceholder" />
      </UnitTest>
    </TestDefinitions>
    <TestLists>
      <TestList name="Results Not in a List" id="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" />
      <TestList name="All Loaded Results" id="19431567-8539-422a-85d7-44ee4e166bda" />
    </TestLists>
<ResultSummary outcome="Completed">
    <Counters total="0" executed="0" passed="0" failed="0" error="0" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
</ResultSummary>
</TestRun>
```